# MacOs zip file - different result when double click and running unzip command

Tags: windows, macos, zip

The following folder is compressed using `Compress-Archive` on a Windows Server:

```
-folder
 |
 - folder1
 | - file1.txt
 |
 - folder2
 | - file2.txt
 |
 - file3.txt
```

When folder is unzipped, the folder structure is correct on Windows and on Mac (while using unzip command in the terminal)

But on Mac when I go to finder, and double click on the file, I get the following folder structure:

```
-folder
 |
 - file1.txt
 - file2.txt
 - file3.txt
```

Comment: I've never had a problem like this. One thing to check: what's your default application for `.zip` files? (Right/Control+click on the .zip file, hover over **Open With** and see what the default is.) That's the app that's going to unzip your file.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Finder questions are on-topic at [AskDifferent](https://askdifferent.com).

Comment: @vonPryz If you read correctly the question, it is not a finder question, its a zipping compress-archive process question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- The problem was when the file was created.
  It was not related to MacOs issue but with certain path length known issue in windows