# zip created using -jr flags unzipped differently on macOS when double clicking vs running unzip

Tags: xcode, bash, scripting, zip, xctest

I am zipping the `.xctest` file from `Plugins` folder inside the `.app` target generated by building my app. I have a build phase script that runs last in my test target to copy this file over. I use the following script to do the zipping:

```
XCTEST_FILE=${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/${TARGET_NAME}.xctest
XCTEST_ZIP=${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}/../../${TARGET_NAME}.xctest.zip
zip -jr ${XCTEST_ZIP} ${XCTEST_FILE}
```

This gives me `TestTarget.xctest.zip` file. But it unzips differently based on these 2 methods,

**unzip TestTarget.xctest.zip**

-TestTarget 
-CodeResources 
-Info.plist

**Double clicking TestTarget.xctest.zip in finder**

-TestTarget.xctest  
--TestTarget  
--CodeResources  
--Info.plist

Why is unzip going to the innermost node and extracting all the files? I want the unzip command to give me the `.xctest` directory. I tried renaming the zip file to `TestTarget.zip` and it still behaves similarly.

I was initially zipping using `zip -r ${XCTEST_ZIP} ${XCTEST_FILE}`, but the problem with this was it would retain the entire folder structure from root (`\`) when I double clicked to unzip the file. A post recommend using the `-j` flag instead of `-r`. But just `-j` led to no zip file being generated. Another comment recommend `-jr` which created a zip that generated output I expected when double clicking it. But I guess the `unzip` command does stuff differently.

Similar Question: [MacOs zip file - different result when double click and running unzip command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54930064/macos-zip-file-different-result-when-double-click-and-running-unzip-command)

The cause for error here was very different,

> The problem was when the file was created. It was not related to MacOs issue but with certain path length known issue in windows

Answer (score 0):

Based on [How to zip folder without full path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11317928/how-to-zip-folder-without-full-path), I had to update my script to first `cd` into the `TARGET_BUILD_DIR` before generating the zip. I also had to remove the `-j` flag so the local folder structure was retained on running `unzip`.

```
cd ${TARGET_BUILD_DIR}
XCTEST_FILE=./${TARGET_NAME}.xctest
XCTEST_ZIP=../../${TARGET_NAME}.xctest.zip
zip -r ${XCTEST_ZIP} ${XCTEST_FILE}
```